# Watchkit Shape Button

Tags: ios, watchkit, wkinterfacebutton

I need a help to make like below buttons to pick colors in Watchkit app.

[image]

For taking group and i can add the button and set the background image of that but click area of each buttons mismatch the click events.

I know how to do in iPhone app but it's quite difficult in watchkit app.

Please tell me the best way to do that.